# RowTemplate not working knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datatables

I am using knockout.js; trying to 'databind' to a Jquery dataTable using a rowTemplate. For some weird reason it returns "No data available in table" implying the dataSource (Users) is empty. However, if I remove the rowTemplate property it works and returns the data in the table as expected. But I really would like to use a RowTemplate.

A polite answer on the problem with my code will be highly appreciated.

```
 <table id="usersTable" data-bind="dataTable:
        {
            dataSource: Users,
            rowTemplate: 'usersRowTemplate',
            iDisplayLength: 6,                
            sPaginationType: 'bootstrap',
            columns: [
                {'name': 'Name'},
                {'name': 'Email'}
            ]
        }"> 
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th></th>                                          
                    </tr>
                </thead> 
                <tbody  >
                </tbody> 
            </table> 

            <script id="usersRowTemplate" type="text/html">
                <td> <input type="text" id="name" data-bind="value: $root.Name" /></td>
                <td> <input type="text" id="email" data-bind="value: $root.Email" /></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.getselecteduser">Details</button>
                </td>
             </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you expect impolite answers? (This is a serious question.)

Comment: FWIW, [I've prepared a Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kW2ka/1/) from what I could conclude about your sample. Please update it to reproduce your exact problem and include the updated Fiddle in your question. (It would have been great if you had provided this right from the start.)

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak. I appreciate your effort. Using Chrome DevTools. I stepped through with breakpoints and discovered that although the dataSource is not empty and actually contains the list of Users, but there's an error in _"Uncaught TypeError:: Cannot call method 'intercept' of undefined"_ at the line _"options.fnRowCallback = cog.utils.intercept(options.fnRowCallback || function (row) { return row; }, function (row, data, displayIndex, displayIndexFull, next)"_ in knockout.bindings.dataTable.js. Although am I able to reproduce it on fiddle. Any idea what may be responsible for this error?

Comment: This would mean that `cog.utils` is not defined, which in turn means you did not correctly include the [CogShift Knockout Extensions](https://github.com/CogShift/Knockout.Extensions) scripts in your page, could that be?

Comment: `cog.utils.js`, `cog.js` and `knockout.bindings.dataTables.js` are all correctly referenced. Using DevTools console I logged the value `options` at the line where the error occurred and I can see that it has the 2 columns `Name` and `Email` as expected. However, it seems it expects `fnRowCallback` to be defined which obviously is not. I tried defining a dummy function and it is still not working.

Comment: Since you say you can reproduce it on jsFiddle, please show me.

Comment: Sorry I mean I cannot reproduce it on Fiddle. But I got it working now. I am not sure where I got my copies of `cog.utils.js` from, but turns out to be the culprit.  I simply removed references to them from my code and copied the one put on [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/WB6yD/3/) and it works like charm. Thanks a lot.